# How to format a column with decimal numbers in QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I have got a QSqlTableModel with decimal numbers in one column. How can I format this column to have numbers with 4 decimal places (e.g.: 2,3 --> 2,3000; 4,567891 --> 4,5679). I am using pyqt5.

Edit:

I tried to subclass QSqlTableModel like this:

```
class AlignmentTable(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
       if role == Qt.DisplayRole and index.column() == 4:
          value = '{:01.4f}'.format(self.data(index))
          return value
```

But I get the error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

2. Edit:

First I load the model like this:

```
def load_sitesizes(self):

    self.mod_site_sizes = AlignmentTable(parent=None, db=dbtools.ProjectDB.use_project_db(self))
    self.mod_site_sizes.setTable("vSiteSizes")

    site_id = str(self.item_id)
    self.mod_site_sizes.setFilter("SiteKey='"+site_id+"'")

    self.mod_site_sizes.select()

    self.mod_site_sizes.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)

    self.tblSiteSizes.setModel(self.mod_site_sizes)
```

and than your code in a subclass:

```
class AlignmentTable(QSqlTableModel):

def data(self, item, role):

    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 4:
            val = QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole)
            if not isinstance(val, float):
                val = float(val)
            return '{:.4f}'.format(round(val, 4))
```

Comment: Consider using `QString::arg ( double a, int fieldWidth = 0, char format = 'g', int precision = -1, const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ) ) ` function in your model.

Comment: Maybe you should read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

Comment: `2,3`  or `2.3`'?

Comment: Numbers with decimals are usually separated by periods, not by commas.

Comment: @eyllanesc, depends on locale. In Germany, for example, it's comma.

Comment: @vahancho  As you are reading from a database, so I ask if they are floating or are strings representing floating.

Comment: I get the data from a SQLite-database. In my model the numbers are shown like this: 2,3

Comment: @vezzon You could show an image of what you get when editing the content please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not access the `self.data(item)` function since you are calling the same function, you must access through the parent: `QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole)`.

period:

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 4:
            val = QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole)
            if not isinstance(val, float):
                val = float(val)
            return '{:.4f}'.format(round(val, 4))
```

commas:

```
def data(self, item, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if item.column() == 4:
            number = round(float(QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole).replace(",", ".")),4)
            return ('{:.4f}'.format(number)).replace(".", ",")
    return QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, role)
```

According to what I observe in your database, the field of column 4 is of decimal type and the problem is that pyqt recognizes it as integer, the solution is simple, you must convert it to floating:

```
class CustomSqlModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QSqlTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setTable("SiteSizes")
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.select()

    def data(self, item, role):
        val = QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, role)
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if item.column() == 4:
                try:
                    return '{:.4f}'.format(round(float(val), 4))
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            if item.column() == 4:
                try:
                    return float(val)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName("zzProjekt1.db")

    model = CustomSqlModel()

    view = QTableView()
    view.resizeColumnsToContents()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setWindowTitle("Custom Model")

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another additional thing is that when editing the default number can be edited 2 decimals, to change it to 4 decimals you can use the following class:

```
class NumberFormatDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setMaximum(10**10)
        editor.setDecimals(4)
        return editor
[...]
view.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, NumberFormatDelegate())
```

*Note: Another thing I've noticed from your database is that vSiteSizes is not a Table, it's a View, and it's read-only, so you can not edit it.*

Comment: @ eyllanesc: I have tried your first suggestion, and it works. But: My table is editable. When I doublechlick the cell to edit the value the cell is emty.

Comment: Could you tell me what you get by executing the following: `print(type(QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.DisplayRole)))`

Comment: <class 'float'>

Comment: I do not see anything, edit your question add it there please.

Comment: Also you could tell me how you created the table in your database to test it.

Comment: I have edited my question a second time. I create the table (vSiteSizes) in my database with a QSQlite-manager (SQLiteStudio). Your second suggestion creates an emty cell.

Comment: What type of field is column 4?

Comment: Could you share your database?

Comment: Okay. One moment please. I will add the picture and the database.

Comment: If you could share the database through drive, dropbox or similar would be great.

Comment: Add the following and tell me what you get, please.       `if role == Qt.EditRole:
         if item.column() == 4:
          print(QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.EditRole))
          print(type(QSqlTableModel.data(self, item, Qt.EditRole)))`

Comment: 2
<class 'int'>

Comment: Here you can find a picture editing the table and the SQLite-database: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/frxg4yuzsga1esw/AABzbhI-YQavZlxNL5RHcOcza?dl=0

Comment: Yes, it is a view, but it is editable. But if I change to the table "sitesize" I have the same result.

Comment: I've updated my code, but test it with the SiteSizes table.

Comment: I have allread set a itemdelegate with 4 decimals to this column. it works great with your code. Thank you!